# Local sites not working with Laravel homestead vagrant setup on ubuntu

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I'm having problems mapping a folder in my vagrant machine to a local laravel website. Instead of mapping `laravel.test` to `code/laravel/public` in the vagrant machine, it maps to localhost.

This is the Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa_homestead.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa_homestead

folders:
    - map: ~/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: laravel.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

Here is `etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# Local websites
127.0.0.1   laravel.test

# other stuff...
```

I know `laravel.test` is being mapped  to `/var/www/html/index.php` because when I access `laravel.test` it prints `phpinfo()`, which is exactly what it prints in `var/www/html/index.php`. I guess what is happening is the folowng: `laravel.test`is mapped to `localhost`, which is mapped to `/var/ww/html/index.php` because I have Apache running on my physical machine. What I need is to map `laravel.test` to my vagrant machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: Vagrant version is 2.2.9 and ubuntu version is 18.04

**UPDATE**

When I access `laravel.test:8000` it does work and I can access my laravel application. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to access the site without specifying the port `8000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `ip` address from the `yaml` in the `hosts` file instead of `127.0.0.1` would work. Same ip address may be used outside of the box while connecting to services such as mysql.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# Local websites
192.168.10.10 laravel.test

# other stuff...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Homestead.yml `sites` as:

```
sites:
    - map: laravel.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/laravel/public
      type: apache
```